# C++ offers std::sort, but does it also offer something to search efficiently?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, stl, std

I have a vector of objects which implement `operator<` and `operator==`. C++ offers std::sort to sort that vector efficiently.

**Is there also a function in std to efficiently search a vector repeatedly?**

I will have many searches on that sorted vector, so std::find does not seem to be a good option, since it just walks through the iterator until it finds a match.

Comment: Is there a reason why you store it in a vector and not in a set / multiset?

Comment: `std::lower_bound` or `std::binary_search` may help.

Comment: @lorro: ...or their unordered_... counterparts.

Comment: @DevSolar: true: it won't be sorted, but it'll be quick on average to search it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, there are.

For example, have a look at [lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) functions.

Also [binary_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) may be useful.

All these functions work on the sorted input and have logarithmic complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Try `std::binary_search` from `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: Only useful if you only need yes/no.